# javascript word count form validations

Tags: javascript, validation, forms, count, cpu-word

I have been trying everything to try and solve this myself, but cannot find any solutions on google or my beginner php skills are not up to the task.  So please can someone show me how I can make the form submit ONLY if people have written 15 words or more.  Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.  Below is the css, javascript and html.

```
#container { 
    background: #ededed; 
    border: 1px solid #ddd; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 638px;
}

.error { color: #f00; }

ol.forms { list-style: none; overflow: hidden; }
ol.forms li { float: left; margin-bottom: 12px; width: 100%; }
ol.forms label { cursor: pointer; display: block; }
ol.forms textarea {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    float: left; 
    font: 14px/1.5em Georgia, Times, serif; 
    height: 120px; 
    margin-right: 5px;
    overflow-y: auto; 
    padding: 5px;
    width: 500px; 
}
ol.forms textarea:focus { border: 1px solid #000; }
ol.forms div.wordCount { float: left; font-size: 20px; line-height: 30px; }

#quick50 {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-size: 11px;
    left: 5px; 
    padding: 5px;
    position: fixed; 
    width: 188px; 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[class^='count[']").each(function() {
        var elClass = $(this).attr('class');
        var description = 0;
        var maxWords = 0;
        var countControl = elClass.substring((elClass.indexOf('['))+1, elClass.lastIndexOf(']')).split(',');

        if(countControl.length > 1) {
            description = countControl[0];
            maxWords = countControl[1];
        } else {
            maxWords = countControl[0];
        }

        $(this).after('<div class="wordCount"><strong>0</strong> Words</div>');
        if(description > 0) {
            $(this).siblings('.wordCount').addClass('error');
        }

        $(this).bind('keyup click blur focus change paste', function() {
            var text = jQuery.trim($(this).val()).replace(/\s+/g," ");
            var numWords = text.split(' ').length;
            if($(this).val() === '') {
                numWords = 0;
            }   
            $(this).siblings('.wordCount').children('strong').text(numWords);

            if(numWords < description || (numWords > maxWords && maxWords != 0)) {
                $(this).siblings('.wordCount').addClass('error');
            } else {
                $(this).siblings('.wordCount').removeClass('error');    
            }

        });

    });
});

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>jQuery Word Count</title>
<link href="wordcount.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wordcount.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <h1>jQuery Word Count</h1>


    <div class="quickContain">
    <div id="quick50">
        <h2>50 words for quick copying</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam leo orci, porta eget, tincidunt sit amet, sagittis id, turpis. Aenean sed metus at leo ullamcorper dapibus. Duis vitae risus dignissim lectus dapibus faucibus! In porttitor, ante non adipiscing ultricies, magna velit blandit dui, a tempus ligula dolor eu orci? Sed.</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <ol class="forms">
        <form action="submitcontent.php" method="post">

        <li><label for="minWord">Min Word Textarea <em class="help">(15 words or more)</em></label>
            <textarea onkeyup="limitWords(this,5);" name="minWord" class="count[15,0]" id="minWord"></textarea>
        </li>


        <input type="submit" value="Submit Content"  onclick="return doSubmit()" />
        </form>
    </ol>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off the top of my head, something like this?

```
<textarea id="some-textarea" onkeypress="activateSubmit();">
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-button" disabled="disabled">
```

And correspondingly somewhere:

```
<script>
  function activateSubmit(){
    var len = $('#some-textarea').val().split(" ").length;
    if(len >= 15){ //15 words, hardcoded, probably change this to maxwords, or whatever.
      $('#submit-button').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else{
      $('#submit-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: @mike... The above approach is honestly your best approach. The basic idea if you weren't sure is that the submit button remains inactive until the activateSubmit() function determines you have the 15 words.  Every time the text form is changed it reevaluates the number of words by creating an array where each element in the array is a single word.  If there are more than 15 it activates the submit button if not it deactivates the submit button.

Comment: This will activate submit when "               " (15 spaces) is entered.

Comment: @mike You should use a combination of enabling submit like this answer using regexps given in the first answer.

Comment: Just tried this out.  Problem is people can still submit an empty text area.  It is not until they start typing in the text area that the submit button disables.  Also, after typing more than 15 words you have to click somewhere outside text area to activate submit button.

Comment: Changed `onchange` to `onkeypress` and added `disabled="disabled"` to the submit button.

Comment: Thanks, your code really helped.  What I ended up doing was inserting your if/else statements into the existing javascript code.  This had the advantage of being less code, plus the minimum word amount is not hardcoded and can be modified in template for example video comments class="count[15,0]" to class="count[30,0]" so users now have to type a minimum of 30 words.

Answer (score 1):

this is an example with a regular expression:

```
$('form#count').submit(function(){
    // if we accept that words are only made of letters
    if ($(this).find('textarea').val().match(/[a-z]+/gi).length < 15) {
        // add some error message
        return false; // prevents submitting
    }
});
```

Comment: But words are not always letters, now are they?
`/\b\w+\b/` is probably a better expression

Comment: In the javascript above there is already a regular expression to filter out blank spaces etc when counting words.  Just need some way to prevent submitting the form if people have not written 15 words or more.  Ideally some kind of javascript solution.